# Key words for test case with pop-up message

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I would like to writing a key words to the test where

1. Upload a file on web page
2. After I can get one of pop-up message: "Operation successful" or "Operation failed"
3. When uploading file was finished with message  "Operation successful" test should will be continue, else test should start again at 1.

I don't know how a key words I may to use to verify text from message.

I wrote something like this, but doesn't work:

```
Run Keyword If  Page Should Contain  Operation successful.  Click Element  xpath://*[@id="modal-button-"]
    ...  ELSE  Run Keywords
    ...  Click Element  xpath://*[@id="modal-button-"]
    ...  Execute Manual Step  "Operation failed. Try again"
```

Comment: Did you mean try to get text and compare ? if so it's possibly duplicated question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299320/robot-framework-get-text

Comment: "Doesn't work" is rather vague. Can you tell us what happens, i.e. any errors that are presented?

Comment: Sidara link that you attached doesn't refer to my questions.

Comment: @A.Kootstra I mean, when I run my test and popup message is displayed, afterward nothing happened. Although there is "Click Element" key words. It is possible that is needed writing it otherwise